# Index of a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

Let $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ be a prime and $u\in\mathbb{Z}$ be such that $u^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$. Now define an additive subgroup $S$ of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ by following, $$S:=\{ (a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}: b\equiv ua\pmod{p}\}$$ Then what is the index of $S$ in $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the group homomorphism 
$$\begin{align}\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z&\to\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z,\\(x,y)&\mapsto y-ux+p\mathbb Z.\end{align}$$
What is its kernel and image? (Side question: Do we care about special properties of $u$ or $p$ at all?)

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

Any subgroup of the free abelian group of rank $\;n\;$ is also free and of rank $\;k\;,\;k\le n\;$ .

If $\;K\le \Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z\;,\;\;K=\langle\;(a,b)\,,\,(c,d)\;\rangle$ , then

$$[\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z:K]=\det\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$$

BTW, notice that it must be $\,p=1\pmod 4\;$...not that this has far-reaching consequences here, though.

Answer (score 0):

Since $(pm)\equiv u(pn)$ mod $p$, $S$ contains $p\mathbb{Z}\times p\mathbb{Z}$, which has index $p^2$. $S$ must therefore have index $1$, $p$, or $p^2$ in $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$. The index is not $1$, since $(1,1)\not\in S$. The index is not $p^2$, since $(-1,u)\in S$ but $(-1,u)\not\in p\mathbb{Z}\times p\mathbb{Z}$.

So the index is $p$.